# fail2ban iptables having port 22 and fails to block ssh on custom port

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables, centos6, fail2ban

This question is almost same problem like mine but accepted answer doesn't solve my issues

[In Fail2Ban, How to Change the SSH port number?](https://serverfault.com/questions/382858/in-fail2ban-how-to-change-the-ssh-port-number)

SSH on port 22 everything works great. After 5 attempts fail2ban reads from logs and bans my ip for 600 seconds. And here is fail2ban log

```
2013-07-10 11:54:08,522 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban 192.168.162.191
2013-07-10 12:04:09,348 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Unban 192.168.162.191
```

My iptables, fail2ban has port 22

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1591 packets, 165K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   44  5292 fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 181 packets, 71152 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   35  4836 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I change SSH port to let say 12345 by editing ssh config

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service sshd restart
```

Now ssh works on port 12345 not 22, totally fine

Logs show my failed login attempts properly

After 5 attempts fail2ban log file displays ban

```
2013-07-10 11:37:33,124 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh-iptables] Ban 192.168.162.191
```

***PROBLEM IS***

But it never bans me from SSH port 12345, I can still access ssh and login

I believe this is because iptables has rule for fail2ban on port 22 but not sure how to edit it. Because if I restart fail2ban it adds it's own rule again with port 22

**EDIT 1:**

*jail.conf*

```
# Fail2Ban jail specifications file
#
# Comments: use '#' for comment lines and ';' (following a space) for inline comments
#
# Changes:  in most of the cases you should not modify this
#           file, but provide customizations in jail.local file, e.g.:
#
# [DEFAULT]
# bantime = 3600
#
# [ssh-iptables]
# enabled = true
#

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be overridden
# in each jail afterwards.

[DEFAULT]

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be
# defined using space separator.
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8

# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.
bantime  = 600

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"
# seconds.
findtime  = 600

# "maxretry" is the number of failures before a host get banned.
maxretry = 3

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification.
# Available options are "pyinotify", "gamin", "polling" and "auto".
# This option can be overridden in each jail as well.
#
# pyinotify: requires pyinotify (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#              If pyinotify is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# gamin:     requires Gamin (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.
#              If Gamin is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.
# polling:   uses a polling algorithm which does not require external libraries.
# auto:      will try to use the following backends, in order:
#              pyinotify, gamin, polling.
backend = auto

# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,
#   warn when DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs
#
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a DNS lookup will be performed.
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a DNS lookup will be performed,
#        but it will be logged as a warning.
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,
#        but it will be logged as info.
usedns = warn


# This jail corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban 0.6.
# The mail-whois action send a notification e-mail with a whois request
# in the body.

[ssh-iptables]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
port     = ssh #TRIED TO PUT HERE 12345 port number but problem persists
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 5

[proftpd-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = proftpd
action   = iptables[name=ProFTPD, port=ftp, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=ProFTPD, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
maxretry = 6

# This jail forces the backend to "polling".

[sasl-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = sasl
backend  = polling
action   = iptables[name=sasl, port=smtp, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=sasl, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log

# ASSP SMTP Proxy Jail
[assp]
enabled  = false
filter   = assp
action = iptables-multiport[name=assp,port="25,465,587"]
logpath  = /root/path/to/assp/logs/maillog.txt

# Here we use TCP-Wrappers instead of Netfilter/Iptables. "ignoreregex" is
# used to avoid banning the user "myuser".

[ssh-tcpwrapper]

enabled     = false
filter      = sshd
action      = hostsdeny
              sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest=you@example.com]
ignoreregex = for myuser from
logpath     = /var/log/sshd.log

# Here we use blackhole routes for not requiring any additional kernel support
# to store large volumes of banned IPs

[ssh-route]

enabled = false
filter = sshd
action = route
logpath = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 5

# Here we use a combination of Netfilter/Iptables and IPsets
# for storing large volumes of banned IPs
#
# IPset comes in two versions. See ipset -V for which one to use
# requires the ipset package and kernel support.
[ssh-iptables-ipset4]

enabled  = false
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables-ipset-proto4[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 5

[ssh-iptables-ipset6]
enabled  = false
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables-ipset-proto6[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp, bantime=600]
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry = 5

# bsd-ipfw is ipfw used by BSD. It uses ipfw tables.
# table number must be unique.
# 
# This will create a deny rule for that table ONLY if a rule 
# for the table doesn't ready exist.
#
[ssh-bsd-ipfw]
enabled  = false
filter   = sshd
action   = bsd-ipfw[port=ssh,table=1]
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 5

# This jail demonstrates the use of wildcards in "logpath".
# Moreover, it is possible to give other files on a new line.

[apache-tcpwrapper]

enabled  = false
filter   = apache-auth
action   = hostsdeny
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log
           /home/www/myhomepage/error.log
maxretry = 6

# The hosts.deny path can be defined with the "file" argument if it is
# not in /etc.

[postfix-tcpwrapper]

enabled  = false
filter   = postfix
action   = hostsdeny[file=/not/a/standard/path/hosts.deny]
           sendmail[name=Postfix, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/postfix.log
bantime  = 300

# Do not ban anybody. Just report information about the remote host.
# A notification is sent at most every 600 seconds (bantime).

[vsftpd-notification]

enabled  = false
filter   = vsftpd
action   = sendmail-whois[name=VSFTPD, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/vsftpd.log
maxretry = 5
bantime  = 1800

# Same as above but with banning the IP address.

[vsftpd-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = vsftpd
action   = iptables[name=VSFTPD, port=ftp, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=VSFTPD, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/vsftpd.log
maxretry = 5
bantime  = 1800

# Ban hosts which agent identifies spammer robots crawling the web
# for email addresses. The mail outputs are buffered.

[apache-badbots]

enabled  = false
filter   = apache-badbots
action   = iptables-multiport[name=BadBots, port="http,https"]
           sendmail-buffered[name=BadBots, lines=5, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/www/*/logs/access_log
bantime  = 172800
maxretry = 1

# Use shorewall instead of iptables.

[apache-shorewall]

enabled  = false
filter   = apache-noscript
action   = shorewall
           sendmail[name=Postfix, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/error_log

# Monitor roundcube server

[roundcube-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = roundcube-auth
action   = iptables[name=RoundCube, port="http,https"]
logpath  = /var/log/roundcube/userlogins


# Monitor SOGo groupware server

[sogo-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = sogo-auth
# without proxy this would be:
# port    = 20000
action   = iptables[name=SOGo, port="http,https"]
logpath  = /var/log/sogo/sogo.log

# Ban attackers that try to use PHP's URL-fopen() functionality
# through GET/POST variables. - Experimental, with more than a year
# of usage in production environments.

[php-url-fopen]

enabled = false
action  = iptables[name=php-url-open, port="http,https"]
filter  = php-url-fopen
logpath = /var/www/*/logs/access_log
maxretry = 1

# A simple PHP-fastcgi jail which works with lighttpd.
# If you run a lighttpd server, then you probably will
# find these kinds of messages in your error_log:
# ALERT – tried to register forbidden variable ‘GLOBALS’
# through GET variables (attacker '1.2.3.4', file '/var/www/default/htdocs/index.php')
# This jail would block the IP 1.2.3.4.

[lighttpd-fastcgi]

enabled = false
filter  = lighttpd-fastcgi
action  = iptables[name=lighttpd-fastcgi, port="http,https"]
# adapt the following two items as needed
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log
maxretry = 2

# Same as above for mod_auth
# It catches wrong authentications

[lighttpd-auth]

enabled = false
filter  = lighttpd-auth
action  = iptables[name=lighttpd-auth, port="http,https"]
# adapt the following two items as needed
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log
maxretry = 2

# This jail uses ipfw, the standard firewall on FreeBSD. The "ignoreip"
# option is overridden in this jail. Moreover, the action "mail-whois" defines
# the variable "name" which contains a comma using "". The characters '' are
# valid too.

[ssh-ipfw]

enabled  = false
filter   = sshd
action   = ipfw[localhost=192.168.0.1]
           sendmail-whois[name="SSH,IPFW", dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
ignoreip = 168.192.0.1

# These jails block attacks against named (bind9). By default, logging is off
# with bind9 installation. You will need something like this:
#
# logging {
#     channel security_file {
#         file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 30m;
#         severity dynamic;
#         print-time yes;
#     };
#     category security {
#         security_file;
#     };
# };
#
# in your named.conf to provide proper logging.
# This jail blocks UDP traffic for DNS requests.

# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Since UDP is connection-less protocol, spoofing of IP and imitation
#   of illegal actions is way too simple.  Thus enabling of this filter
#   might provide an easy way for implementing a DoS against a chosen
#   victim. See
#    http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/690-fail2ban-+-dns-fail.html
#   Please DO NOT USE this jail unless you know what you are doing.
#
# [named-refused-udp]
#
# enabled  = false
# filter   = named-refused
# action   = iptables-multiport[name=Named, port="domain,953", protocol=udp]
#            sendmail-whois[name=Named, dest=you@example.com]
# logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log
# ignoreip = 168.192.0.1

# This jail blocks TCP traffic for DNS requests.

[named-refused-tcp]

enabled  = false
filter   = named-refused
action   = iptables-multiport[name=Named, port="domain,953", protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=Named, dest=you@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log
ignoreip = 168.192.0.1

# Multiple jails, 1 per protocol, are necessary ATM:
# see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/37
[asterisk-tcp]

enabled  = false
filter   = asterisk
action   = iptables-multiport[name=asterisk-tcp, port="5060,5061", protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=Asterisk, dest=you@example.com, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages
maxretry = 10

[asterisk-udp]

enabled  = false
filter   = asterisk
action   = iptables-multiport[name=asterisk-udp, port="5060,5061", protocol=udp]
           sendmail-whois[name=Asterisk, dest=you@example.com, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages
maxretry = 10

# To log wrong MySQL access attempts add to /etc/my.cnf:
# log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
# log-warning = 2
[mysqld-iptables]

enabled  = false
filter   = mysqld-auth
action   = iptables[name=mysql, port=3306, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=MySQL, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/mysqld.log
maxretry = 5


# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers
# !!! WARNING !!!
#   Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local
#   is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into
#   an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines
[recidive]

enabled  = false
filter   = recidive
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]
           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day
maxretry = 5

# PF is a BSD based firewall
[ssh-pf]

enabled=false
filter = sshd
action = pf
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log
maxretry=5
```

Comment: Could you please show us your jail configuration?

Comment: ok added conf file

Comment: @Ergec  you have to modify the standard  ssh port found in  /etc/services  You have there  ssh   22/tcp    Change the port that suits your needs.

Comment: @val0x00ff add you comment as answer because that was exactly what I need. I'll accept your answer. Seems fail2ban uses ports in /etc/services to create iptables rules. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ergec,  No problem. Though specifying the port as  12345 in the `action` section.. would also work since you are hardcoding the port.  `port=ssh` was ofcourse mapped to port 22.

Comment: Ok seems I have two correct answers from @quanta and val0x00ff and both solve my problem. But I'll pick val0x00ff because it seems like a more global fix. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using  ssh as port name it is going to search on  /etc/services file and map the name `ssh` to the associated port which is `22`

You can simply modify the `/etc/services` file and change port `22/tcp` to whatever you like.

Save changes and you are done!

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the default port in the `action` line, something like this:

```
[ssh-iptables]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=12345, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-whois[name=SSH, dest=root, sender=fail2ban@example.com]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 5
```

Don't forget to restart the fail2ban after that.

Comment: This answer also fixed my problem. Thanks a lot @quanta up voted

Answer (score 4):

Copy paste from my `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`
Works fine and let me change on one place for both TCP/22 and TCP/2222

```
[ssh]
enabled = true
port = ssh,2222
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 4
```