# fail2ban and ssh don't work

Tags: ssh, fail2ban

I have configured ssh with port 2122
and pubkey only.
I secured but i want more banning
the lamers wich try bruteforce auth.

My configuration of fail2ban

```
jail.local

[INCLUDES]
before = paths-slackware.conf
[DEFAULT]
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
ignorecommand =
bantime  = 10800
findtime  = 600
maxretry = 3
backend = auto
usedns = warn
logencoding = auto
enabled = true
filter = %(__name__)s
destemail = root@localhost
sender = root@localhost
mta = mail
protocol = tcp
chain = INPUT
port = 0:65535
fail2ban_agent = Fail2Ban/%(fail2ban_version)s
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
action_xarf = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             xarf-login-attack[service=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, port="%(port)s"]
action_cf_mwl = cloudflare[cfuser="%(cfemail)s", cftoken="%(cfapikey)s"]
                %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
action_blocklist_de  = blocklist_de[email="%(sender)s", service=%(filter)s, apikey="%(blocklist_de_apikey)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips = badips.py[category="%(__name__)s", banaction="%(banaction)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action_badips_report = badips[category="%(__name__)s", agent="%(fail2ban_agent)s"]
action = %(action_)s
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = 22
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/messages
maxretry = 3
findtime = 10800
bantime = 21600
[apache]
enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-auth
logpath  = /var/chroothttp/var/log/httpd/error_log
maxretry = 3
findtime = 10800
bantime = 21600
```

Apache is working perfect,I have tried
some bad logins and ban the ip's
But ssh try and retry..no ban!

Comment: What port are you connecting to your server on and expecting to be banned ?

Comment: 22 the default ssh port

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found a definitive solution

```
mode   = aggressive
```

instead of

```
mode = normal
```

Now fail2ban ban the attempts with pubkey if user is invalid or port wrong, etc.
Tested and work, this is jail.local sshd part for Slackware 15
In this example I use standard 22 port, but I've also tested it with another port (2122) and works.

```
[sshd]
    mode     = aggressive
    enabled  = true
    port     = ssh
    logpath  = /var/log/messages
    backend  = %(sshd_backend)s
    filter   = sshd
    maxretry = 2
    findtime = 10800
    bantime = 24h
```

Comment: You must have also changed the configuration for the port number you told us about in the question - since that is what was preventing fail2ban from blocking connections.

Comment: With a different port number I try it now

Comment: I have tried with different port number and works perfectly using mode = aggressive

Answer (score 1):

If SSH is not running on port 22, there will not be failed login attempts logged into `/var/log/messages`, and therefore Fail2Ban has no information on which IP addresses to ban.

However, since you don't have any service running on port 22, you don't actually need banning.

Comment: You do not need to ban failed SSH auth of you changed port and also going with key only. ++ to this

Comment: On log messages i see  Connection from  Connection closed

Comment: Can you copy the exact log line into your question? It is difficult to understand the description above..

Answer (score 1):

If you're running ssh on a non-standard port, you need to update your fail2ban config to pay attention to that port, not just the named service (because it assumes the named service is running on its standard port).

Quoting from another [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382891/2321):

> fail2ban will detect login attemps with log content. fail2ban don't use ports for detection, only to block.
>   To block the right port, you have to tell fail2ban which one in order to correctly setup iptable.
>   Into `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:
>
> `[ssh]`
>   `enabled  = true`
>   `port     = ssh   <-- just modify this with your port    port = 1234`

Then restart fail2ban.

Comment: I did it and..nothing happen

Comment: @elbarna - there shouldn't be much that "happens" if you're on a non-standard port: very few (if any) attacks are going to come across that vector